# How can I get job as a self-taught developer with no degree or certification?

Tags: job-search, career-development, internship, developer

I'm 26, an undergraduate in B.A, a year ago I started Python from YouTube, I have finished the course and started doing freelance from Fiverr, did multiple projects, now I am learning JavaScript to enhance my knowledge to web development so that I can leverage my python knowledge as a full stack developer, I love programming.
What should I do to get a job? Or is there any scope for me?

Comment: Apply, Apply, Apply, then you'll hopefully get feedback on why you're not hired.

Comment: What country are you based in?

Comment: Does B.A. = Business Administration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get interviews as a self-taught programmer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115903/how-to-get-interviews-as-a-self-taught-programmer)

Comment: Why would you want to be a employee when you are building a programming business already? That is a far bigger scope. Knowing how to run a business and have programming skills is very sellable.

Comment: @Maxime, I wouldn't rely on that. The chances of getting honest feedback are slim in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

> What should I do to get a job?

Keeping studying. Keep practicing. Keep taking projects where and when you can. Apply for the jobs you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way is to leverage your network. People who know and trust your skills (or family). Many people have whole careers built this way just expanding their network and putting out the work without problems.

Some use it as a stepping stone and get qualified along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the self taught-programmers managed to get hired for cheap by a company based on a portfolio and then used that to build a career.

There are several things you can do.

1. If your work is public, and you have the client's permission, add links to your work.
2. Have an active GitHub where you post personal projects your working on.
3. Consider starting a blog about your journey.  Sometimes you may be invited to speak at local "Learn To Code" meetups.
4. Check Facebook, Meetup, and other websites for meetings in your area about technologies you're interested in.  They are likely virtual now due to COVID, but still consider logging in.
5. Reddit has several "Learn to Code" subreddits which will are very newbie friendly.  Start networking with others who are also learning to code.
6. Work for very little money (at first).  It's best if you get hired, even on a contract bases, by a company that you can put on your resume (i.e. not Fiverr).

Finally, continue learning on your own.

Comment: I do not agree with 6. When I got started I worked for very little money "to get a reputation", as they say, and I got a reputation as the guy who works for very little money, which was not helpful. Also by undercutting others you ruin the landscape for the people who want to make a living from their work (which is you at some point, so everybody loses).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's just look at what you want: you want a job with one year of youtube tutorials.

Would *you* be willing to do that?

Would *you* be okay with your dentist being a person having watched a lot of youtube drilling tutorials?

Would *you* be okay if the person handling your electricity in the house says "I know this, I learned all about it last year on youtube".

Would *you* be okay if you tax accountant said "Don't worry, I got this, I saw the youtube video at least 30 times".

My guess is you would not. You want people to be professionals. You want them to have a solid 2-5 year education before they do stuff. So do employers.

The way to a job, almost *any* job worth having is *education*. Theoretical, practical, depends on the job. But with a real curriculum, a real teacher and real feedback for learning (that you don't get from watching videos).

I don't know what options you have where you live, but the times where random people from the street where picked up for their hobbyist skills in computer programming is 40 years past now.

Computer Science is mainstream now and employers expect mainstream credentials.

You need an education.

Comment: As someone with a CS degree, you don't learn jack in regards to the programming.  The OP can most likely outprogram 90% of CS grads from learning off YouTube.  Learning about algorithms, data structures, Big O and all that is nice and all but unless you're doing actual computer science, it will be forgotten.  Only like 1% of jobs is at Google or Facebook doing some complex algorithm design, 99% are building CRUD apps for businesses.  That being said, try to get a diploma in software development.

Comment: Indeed, it does not need to be a college degree in CS. Where I live, apprenticeships in software development are an option. They take just as long as a BS, but focus more on practical programming skills and things you need in the average company.

Comment: The OP already has a 4 year degree.  I've know several developers who are self taught via youtube. Best way is to find someone willing to hire you for peanuts and keep getting raises and promotions.

Comment: I'll echo @Jack here since I also have a CS bachelor's. I know for a fact you don't need a CS degree to do my software engineer job because my company specifically trained non-CS people to do it. I think CS is great and tended to result in higher-quality code, but not always.

Comment: "my company specifically trained non-CS people to do it" isn't that what I said? "a real teacher and real feedback for learning". I never said college degree in CS. I said education. Apprenticeship, college degree, something in between, that's all valid education and depends on what is offered in your region of the world.

Comment: I don't feel like dentists or electricians are a good comparison here because they do not have a QA team, unit tests, code review and all the rest of it. They do their jobs without much oversight. Programmers do not work this way, least of all junior ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have a degree that's completely unrelated to my job. My degree is in languages, now I am a software developer. After graduating, I was a cleaner for a bit (mostly just so I could eat). And then I took a job in IT (some blackbox testing, changing toners, helping people do their spreadsheets etc. etc. etc.) That job gradually involved more and more programming. Meanwhile in my spare time I was doing some vaguely related hobbies. Some years later I have a solid enough background in embedded programming that I've gotten hired to do that.

So there's an approach you could take.

Comment: Hi,  Can I ask what language did you learn for embedded programming?

Comment: @questioner, Sure. I started with C and Python. I know a few assembler languages as well, so that I can at least reason about what my compilers are doing. After this, I've learned some Rust as well, which I hope to apply to my embedded stuff some time.

Comment: @questioner Oh and also, I did some projects that are openly available on github. That's been useful for prospective employers to see my style/approach.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is build some project while learning, so you can showcase your skills with more than a "I know this and that".

Once you have something interesting enough go out there and share what you've built :)

Comment: And when you do build projects, make sure that you have stuff publicly available (like on your GitHub), so that prospective employers can see you writing your own stuff, and contributing to existing open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a degree that would lead to programming positions. I do have a college degree, just not one that is universally accepted for programming jobs.

So how do I always end up with a job that requires that I spend time each week programming? I apply for jobs that are mostly related to  my main degree, but do have a programming aspect. These are jobs that only list the ability to code in additional or nice to have requirements.  Then I do my best to morph the job into one where the programming skills I have are the thing they remember about me. Eventually I can transfer into roles that have even more programming requirements.

So my advice is don't go for jobs that are 100% developer, go for ones that are 25% developer. Then build from there.

Comment: What kinds of jobs would have a programming aspect? My first thought was office admin jobs that ask for spreadsheet programming etc, but I'd like to know more.